# Combined Multiple Column Index as well as Multiple Single Column Indices

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I want to know what is harm in defining both type of indices together in the following situation.

Table `Tasks`:

```
  TaskID (Primary, Auto Number)
  OwnerID (Single Column Index)
  AssignedToID (Single Column Index)
  DateUpdated (Single Column Index)
  TaskStatus (Single Column Index)

  Mutli Column Index (AssignedToID, DateUpdated)
```

There are following major queries... queries to `DateUpdated` is optional.

- Admin can filter tasks on dates
- Single Column Index DateUpdated is accessed

  ```
  WHERE 
      DateUpdated <= startDate 
      AND DateUpdated <= endDate
  ORDER BY
      DateUpdated DESC
  ```
- Single Column Index DateUpdated is accessed

  ```
  WHERE
       TaskStatus = 'Active' 
  ORDER BY
       DateUpdated DESC
  ```
- User can filter tasks only assigned to them
- Multi Column Index is accessed

  ```
  WHERE 
      DateUpdated <= startDate 
      AND DateUpdated <= endDate
      AND AssignedToID = userID
  ORDER BY
      DateUpdated DESC
  ```
- Multi Column Index is accessed

  ```
  WHERE 
       AssignedToID = userID
       AND TaskStatus = 'Active'
  ORDER BY
       DateUpdated DESC
  ```
- `DateUpdated` is no referenced in any criteria
- Single Column Index `TaskID` is accessed

  ```
  WHERE 
      AssignedToID = userID
      AND TaskStatus = 'Active'
  ORDER BY
      TaskID DESC
  ```

It looks like I can improve performance by defining multiple column index in certain frequent queries, I have following questions.

1. Is there any harm on defining both combined index as well as multiple indices?
2. Will SQL give preference to combined index over single index merge if query contains predicate with each column regardless of order of column in query?
3. If you have any example of where both indexes could be harmful, I will like to learn why and how, so I can design my indexes accordingly.

My database operations are 95% read and 5% write, so I am less worried about index write performance issue, but my read performance is most important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any harm on defining both combined index as well as multiple indices?

I would rather call it maintenance overhead than harm:
- INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on this table will be a bit slower with every new index.
- Index takes some disk space.

> Will SQL give preference to combined index over single index merge if query contains predicate with each column regardless of order of column in query?

Order of columns in a query does not matter.

Order of columns in an index does matter.
So:
index on (`AssignedToID`, `DateUpdated`) can be used for seek instead of the index on (`AssignedToID`), but
index on (`DateUpdated`, `AssignedToID`) cannot be used for seek instead of the index on (`AssignedToID`).

Query optimizer will choose which index to use based on the estimated cost, which it calculates based on statistics (how many rows in the table/index, and how values are distributed).
It might decide not to use your index at all - if the number of rows is small and it is cheaper to scan the whole table, or if index is not selective enough.

If a query contains predicate on `AssignedToID` and `DateUpdated` - the index on (`AssignedToID`, `DateUpdated`) is more likely to be used by query optimizer than index on (`AssignedToID`).
However it depends on all other elements of the query and the actual data in your DB.

> If you have any example of where both indexes could be harmful, I will like to learn why and how, so I can design my indexes accordingly.

The overhead might become noticeable when the database, or/and number of requests grows significantly.

[More about "too many indexes"](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/indexes-just-because-you-can-doesnt-mean-you-should/)
[General indexing guidelines](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095.aspx#Nonclustered)

---

Based on your major queries it looks like the non-clustered indexes should be:

- (`DateUpdated`)
- (`AssignedToID`, `DateUpdated`)

Maybe:

- (`TaskStatus`) - however if let's say 90% of tasks are `'Active'` and you only query `'Active'` - then it's of no use.

Not needed:

- (`AssignedToID`) - because (`AssignedToID`, `DateUpdated`) index will be sufficient.

After that you could verify the assumptions on a test DB, with data close enough to production.